# In triangle $ABC,$ $\angle ABC = 30^{\circ}$ and $AB = 10$. $AC=AD$ can be $5, 7, 9 \rm{\ or \ } 11$. How many scalene triangles are there?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

[image]

I do not understand the solution given. The answer is 6.

Here is the solution:

When $AC = 5$, it is a right-angled triangle; there is 1.

When $AC = 7,9,$ there are $4$.

When $AC = 11,$ there is $1$.

Total $= \boxed{6}$

What I do not understand is why we say that there is only 1 scalene for when $AC = 5$. I understand that we know that it is a right triangle because $\sin 30^{\circ} = {1 \over 2}$, but I don't get why there is only $1$ scalene when $ABD$ could be a side that does not have $5$. I also don't get why we have $4$ scalenes for when $AC = 7$ and $9$. Lastly, how do we know that there is only $1$ scalene triangle when $AC = 11$?

Comment: This is kind of weird, but the idea is if you actually try to draw the diagram with $AB=10$, $AC=AD=5$ and $\angle ABC=30^\circ$, you'll end up with $C$ coinciding with $D$. Simply put, the diagram is misleading for the case when $AC=AD=5$.

Comment: In case $AC=11$ the point $D$ doesn't lie on $BC$ anymore.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe i dont understand why it doesnt lie on BC anymore. Can you please explain?

Comment: Well, as $AB=10$ and $AD=11$, $D$ wouldn't lie on the segment $BC$ but left of $B$ outside the triangle $ABC$.